# Missing Title on Facebook Plugin - Joomla 1.5

Tags: facebook, joomla, title

I'm working on a blog page for a site that's currently running on Joomla 1.5 (slowly rolling out upgraded templates but I need this one to work in the meantime).

I'm using the Facebook like box and have the Facebook header set to 'false' I've got the module title set to show, but it's not appearing on the page. The Facebook code is set in a custom module and I have several other custom modules on the page with functional titles.

I've got the same set up on a separate blog page in Joomla 3 that is working without issues. Is this just a lack of compatibility with Joomla 1.5?

Here's the page for your review http://discoverestevan.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=22&Itemid=455

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but I ended up using an ID within the module that applied to the 'header' space of the Facebook widget. Note that I could not leave it the default ID name or it applied the title styles to a checker div at the top of the page with the same ID name.

I used :before to write the title text in via CSS. The final CSS code looks like this:

```
#fb-head {
    background: rgb(212, 31, 60); /*Logo Colour: #b31c27*/
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

#fb-head:before {
    content: "Find Us on Facebook";
    color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

With this custom module code:

```
<div id="fb-head" class="hidden_div">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/CJ1280-Radio/168180086627809?ref=ts&amp;fref=ts" data-height="513px" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false">&nbsp;</div>
```